# Computing $(\mathbb R \times \mathbb Z) \cup (\mathbb Z \times \mathbb R)$ and $(\mathbb R \times \mathbb Z) \cap (\mathbb Z \times \mathbb R)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, logic

I have a question regarding $(\mathbb R \times \mathbb Z) \cup (\mathbb Z \times \mathbb R)$ and $(\mathbb R \times \mathbb Z) \cap (\mathbb Z \times \mathbb R)$.

The questions are:

> $(\mathbb R \times \mathbb Z) \cup (\mathbb Z \times \mathbb R) = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R~~~~~~~~~$  true or false
>
> $(\mathbb R \times \mathbb Z) \cap (\mathbb Z \times \mathbb R) = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z~~~~~~~~~$
>   true of false

What we have learned in class is that $\mathbb R \times \mathbb Z = \{(x,y): x \in \mathbb R, y \in \mathbb Z\}$, however we didn't do any examples on their union. So, i'm not certain if my logic is correct.

So, for $\mathbb R \times \mathbb Z) \cup (\mathbb Z \times \mathbb R) = \mathbb R \times \mathbb R$, i think it's true because, $(x \in \mathbb R) \cup (x \in \mathbb Z)$ is real number since $\mathbb Z \subseteq \mathbb R$ and it's the union of $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb R$. Wlog for $y$.

and for $(\mathbb R \times \mathbb Z) \cap (\mathbb Z \times \mathbb R) = \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$, i think it's true, because $\mathbb Z \subseteq \mathbb R$ so, $(x \in \mathbb R) \cap (x \in \mathbb  Z) =$ integers only.

I don't know, but i feel my logic is completely flawed ...

Could anyone please help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Was it really necessary to write 6(!!!) tiny comments? Usually we want to keep the comment section clean and as short as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try visualizing. Consider the $xy$-plane (i.e.: $\mathbb R \times \mathbb R$).

We can visualize $\mathbb R \times \mathbb Z$ by drawing a horizontal line through the origin and then continuing above and below, each one unit apart (i.e.: the lines $y = 0, y = \pm 1, y = \pm 2, \ldots$).

Likewise, we can visualize $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb R$ by drawing a vertical line through the origin and then continuing to the left and to the right, each one unit apart (i.e.: the lines $x = 0, x = \pm 1, x = \pm 2, \ldots$).

For the union, ask yourself: do the horizontal and vertical lines completely cover the plane? If not, where are the gaps?

For the intersection, ask yourself: do the horizontal and vertical lines ever cross each other? If so, where?

Comment: Thank you so much for the insight! I was so stuck up with sets and subsets that I never tried to visualize it. The graph of the union and intersection of (R×Z) and (Z×R) looks like grid layout on the Cartesian plane. And for the intersection,  (R×Z) and (Z×R) intersects at every (x,y): x∈Z,y∈Z.  So (R×Z)∩(Z×R)=Z×Z is True. And for the union, since it's a grid, the lines don't cover the whole plane, and that's because the gaps are at (x,y): x,y∈R. Since the y in RxZ) is integer and the x in (ZxR) is integer, so it can't possibly cover the whole plane, so false for union. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. Any ordered pair containing two non-integer numbers (like $(0.5, \pi)$) will not be covered by any horizontal or vertical lines.